# Input Box into a loop only insert last entry

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to have a loop of input boxes where each input box has the content of cells in column A, and the input asked should end in the cell next to it (column B); like shown in the picture. The good news (for me) is that the loop works, but after I have filled each input box, the macro registers only the last entry in the entire range (in this case not approved, while for instance the first two entries were "approved"). Could you give me a hand? Thanks in advance! (code below).

[image]

```
Sub inputresults()

 Dim myvalue As Variant
 Dim c As Range, rngc As Range, i As Long, lrow As Long

i = 3
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rngc = Range(Cells(lrow, "A"), Cells(i, "A"))
    For Each c In rngc
        myvalue = InputBox(c)
    Next

Dim cl As Range, clrng As Range, lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set clrng = Range(Cells(lastrow, "B"), Cells(i, "B"))
    For Each cl In clrng
        cl.Value = myvalue
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one loop here. You can write the inputted value by referring to column B using `Offset`.

```
For Each c In rngc
    myvalue = InputBox(c.Value)
    c.Offset(,1).Value = myvalue
Next
```

Or more simply:

```
For Each c In rngc
    c.Offset(,1).Value = InputBox(c.Value)
Next
```